# Discord JS getting current channel ID

Tags: discord.js

Is there a way to grab the ID of the current channel a message is sent? I would like to store the channel ID in a variable I set already. Just need to grab the id of the channel where my message is sent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `message.channel.id`, when you receive a message that is resulted from a `client.on("message", message => {})` event, you can call `message.channel.id` from it's property, for more explanations, read the docs [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=channel). An example of it would be:

```js
client.on("message", message => {
  // The channel id can be received through `message.channel.id` and is stored in the variable `messageChannelId`
  const messageChannelId = message.channel.id;
  // This will log in the console the id of the channel that it's being sent from
  console.log(messageChannelId);
})
```

If you would like to see how a `message` event is constructed, use instead:

```js
client.on("message", message => {
  // Logs in the console the `message` property
  console.log(message);
})
```

If you would like to see how a `message.channel` property looks like, use:

```js
client.on("message", message => {
  // Logs in the console the `message.channel` prroperty
  console.log(message.channel);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call on the [`channel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=channel) property of the [`message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) object (referring to the channel the message was sent in). From there, you have access to the entire [`TextChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel) object!

```js
message.channel.name; // name of channel
message.channel.guild; // guild the channel's in
message.channel.topic; // topic of the channel
message.channel.parent; // category of which the channel is in

message.channel.id; // and finally, the id of the channel
```

Answer (score -1):

For a message event, use the message object and get its guild.
Like so:

```js
client.on('message', async message => {
  var channel = message.channel;
})
```

Here is the documentation for `Channel`: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Channel

Comment: That's not what was asked though?

Comment: Sorry, I meant channel.